# How can I average individual columns for hundreds of files in Python most efficiently without big data infrastructure?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, bigdata

What I am trying to do is, for each file, take the average of each column. Then append the result as a new row in a DataFrame or exported file. So essentially I would have a new file where each row is the result for a single file.

I've already done this successfully. In other words, the code I wrote *works*. However, it obviously takes too long when I add more data, something I need to do. I did my best when I started to write this code to make the most use of dictionaries I could because from reading other threads on this site, that seemed to be the best route. This is a flow chart of what my code does right now:

[image: flowchart]

I suspect the lists and DataFrames in here might be bottlenecks, which is why I was hoping someone might have another idea of how to handle this data. The fact that dictionaries are unordered in Python is why I was careful to zip the lists and add the date column before moving on to the next file. Ultimately I would want to store the result in a .csv file for later use.

This is the first time I've had to try managing big data without big data infrastructure (company I work for is several months away from that kind of investment), so performance wasn't a big issue for me in the past. So I'd love some advice on how to manage this task better.

If it helps, my work laptop has a Xeon E-2176M processor, NVIDIA Quadro P4200 graphics card, and 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: In one of my courses, we used mmap to read and perform calculations on a local machine. It might be worth checking out for this application. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap] An example is located here [https://github.com/sapling19/CSE6242-Data-Visual-Analytics/tree/master/HW4/Q1]

Comment: I'd bet on IO being the bottleneck. Loading files from disk (even SSD) isn't fast so you want to minimize that. If most of your CSV files don't change often, store the results into a `summary.csv`. The next time your program runs, consult this file and ignore files that are already in here